# Show data object under a different name

Tags: silverstripe

Below is my Customer dataobject

```
<?php
 class Customer extends DataObject {
static $db = array(
    'FirstName' => 'Varchar',
    'Surname' => 'Varchar',
    'Email' => 'Varchar',
    'CustomerType' => "Enum('Private,Business','Private')"
);
static $has_one = array(
    'Avatar' => 'Image',
);
static $has_many = array(
    'HostingContracts' => 'HostingContract'
);
static $summary_fields = array(
    'FirstName',
    'Surname',
    'CustomerType'
);
static $searchable_fields = array(
    'FirstName',
    'Surname',
    'HostingContracts.ContractNumber'
);
    }
    ?>
```

I need "Customer" to show as "Client" without changing the class name of the object.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Customer extends DataObject {
  static $singular_name = 'Client';
  static $plural_name = 'Clients';
}
```